# Highlight specific days

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to highlight certain days (obtained by an AJAX feed I can design to my liking) and then be able to capture click events on such days:

[image: Design concept]

I've had a look at the [`events` handler](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) but it's clearly designed to display individual events and I'm not sure if it can be tweaked to do what I want. Can you figure out a way to just add a class name to those days and then style it with CSS?

*I'm using FullCalendar v2.3.2 (upgrading is not really an option because it's already used all around the site).*

Comment: Have you looked at creating a custom view handler, ? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/  It would look like you could use the `render` callback, ..

Comment: @Keith Thank you, I'm playing with the concept while I type but I don't really know what `render` callback you mean.

Comment: Hi, I've created a snippet,.. While playing I noticed a dayRender callback..  I think that should do what your after..

Answer (score 1):

I've modified to do a pretend ajax call,..  Basically waits a 1 second, as if doing an ajax call etc, and then re-renders.

The only thing that's not nice is how I've done the refresh, there might be a better way.  The render method doesn't re-render the view.

You can then modify to do other stuff, from data you get from ajax.

```js
var dtoday = moment().dayOfYear();
var days = [];

function pretendAjax() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    days = [dtoday - 2, dtoday + 2];   
    //force calendar refresh, there might be a better
    //way than below, but will do for now
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView','basicWeek');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView','month');
  }, 1000);
}


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    var dofyear = date.dayOfYear();
    if (days.indexOf(dofyear) >= 0) {
      cell.css({backgroundColor: 'pink'});
    }
  },
});

pretendAjax();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.css' />


<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks promising, but apparently days are rendered before even AJAX starts. At `dayRender` I still don't have the information.

Comment: You can call your ajax, get the data first.. And then refresh the calendar.

Comment: I've written a function-based `events` handler that fetches my data. How can I trigger a refresh or, alternatively, loop the days myself?

Comment: You've given a lot of ideas, which helped me figure out a hack that seems to do the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've composed this ugly hack, which is mostly a proof on concept that reveals my deep ignorance of FullCalendar API and still needs lots of optimising (for instance, we should remove references to cells that no longer exist).

I'm abusing the initial `dayRender` execution to store cells in a custom variable. I can then access that variable to my liking and apply any jQuery function of my choice to the linked cell, which is a good old jQuery object.

```js
var days = {};
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
        days[date.toISOString()] = cell;
    },
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback){
        // Emulated AJAX response
        var data = [
            start.add(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            start.add(2, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            start.add(5, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        ];
        $.map(data, function(elementOfArray){
            days[elementOfArray].addClass("has-stuff");
            callback([]);
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.has-stuff {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.css' />


<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Optimising aside, it sill needs additional work to implement click events on highlighted days.

*Credits go to Keith for the initial snippet skeleton, errors are all mine.*

Comment: Nice, you know I'm sure I tried using the events callback, but when I called the callback([]), it didn't seem to refresh the view for me..  Might have been another event I used.. Anyway glad you got it all sorted..